# References about clustered linear regression

Tags: regression, clustering, nonlinear-regression

I have to write a project about clustered linear regression.
The only resource I have been able to find is https://doi.org/10.1016/S0950-7051(01)00154-X
Any other articles/books that you can point me to please?